# How to use varargs as parameters of newInstance() to call a constructor and create an instance?

Tags: java, reflection, variadic-functions, java-9

I'm an autodidact and I'm trying to do this homework, but I didn't find any solution yet.

I don't know how to use varargs.I can't pass them to the newInstance() method to invoke the constructor that I need.
But the main problem is that I would like to write them from the command line using "args" but I don't know how to do.

Please any advice? Thanks a lot!

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.io.*;

public class VarargsTest{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
        Class theClass = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try{
            theClass = Class.forName(args[0]); // what class I want to use ?
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.out.println(theClass);
        Object obj = null;
        System.out.print("number of constructor's parameters :"); 
        String buf = null;
        try{
            buf = br.readLine(); //Waiting the number of parameters for the constructor
        }
        catch(IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        Constructor[] constructors = theClass.getConstructors(); // constructor of that class
        for(Constructor constructor : constructors) {
            if(constructor.getParameterCount() == Integer.parseInt(buf)) {//checking that the number of parameters are matching
                if(constructor.getParameterTypes()[0] == VarargsC.class){// IL PRIMO PARAMETRO DEL COSTRUTTORE DEVE ESSERE DEL TIPO DELLA CLASSE

                    try{

                        obj = constructor.newInstance(new Object[]{"first", "second"," more"}); // trying some elements, but I would like use args[1]
                    }
                    catch(InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.exit(1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("There isn't a constructor with " + buf + " parameters");
        System.out.println();
        if(obj != null) {
            System.out.println("I have instantiate an object!");
            System.out.println(obj);
        }else{
            System.out.println("I'm not able to instantiate an object'");
        }
    }
}

class VarargsC{
    String str1;
    String str2;
    String str3;
        public VarargsC(String str1, String str2, String str3){
            this.str1 = str1;   
            this.str2 = str2;
            this.str3 = str3;
        }
        public String toString(){
            return "VarargsC{" +
                    "str1=" + str1 +"\n" +
                    "str2=" + str2 +"\n" +
                    "str3=" + str3 + "\n" + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
}


/*class VarargsC{

    String[] data;
        public VarargsC(String... str){
            data = new String[5];
            for(int i= 0; i< str.length; i++)
                                for(String a: str)
                this.data[i] = a;
        }

        public void toString(String... str){
            for(String a: str)
                System.out.println(a + "\n");
        }
}*/
```

Comment: Is the problem that you want to pass an array as a single argument but each element is passed individually, or vice versa? Or is the problem something else?

Comment: @Slaw Yes, for example I would like pass a string of 3 word's like this : "first, second, third" on "args[1]" and then passed each word individually as a parameter on newInstance()

Comment: If your constructor's parameter is varargs (which is just syntactic sugar for an array) then using either `newInstance(new Object[]{array})` or `newInstance((Object) array)` should work for you. If you're having an issue, please [edit] your question to provide a [mre] and the exact error(s) you're getting.

Comment: @Slaw Thanks for your reply, but I didn't solve the problem yet.Your solution was helpful, but it doesn't solve my problem. I don't really understand what's wrong with my code. I made some changes but the situation has not improved much, I show you!

Comment: If you could create a [mre] (← read the linked help page) demonstrating the problem I may be able to help more. Your current code seems to contain unnecessary code with regards to your specific question (i.e. it's not _minimal_) which makes it more difficult to understand what should be happening or what exactly is the problem. If you could also provide some sample inputs and expected outputs that would be helpful.

Comment: @Slaw ok I will do, thank. It's almost one week that I'm here this is the way that I'm so lazy. But I will do it until tomorrow morning. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

The *varargs* feature of the Java programming language allows to call a method, which supports a variable number of arguments, like an ordinary method with *n* arguments *in source code*. It is unrelated to your intent to allow an arbitrary number of arguments *on the command line*.

In fact, this source code feature is not even needed for your operation. You receive the command line arguments in an array whose length reflects their number. You can check the array length using `args.length`.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      if(args.length == 0) {
          System.err.println("specify <className> args...");
          System.exit(1);
      }

      String className = args[0];
      // remove the first element
      args = Arrays.copyOfRange(args, 1, args.length);

      Class<?> theClass;// don't initialize with null
      try {
          theClass = Class.forName(className);
      }
      catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          System.exit(1);
          throw new AssertionError(); // unreachable point
      }

      // constructor accepting n strings
      Class<?>[] argTypes = new Class[args.length];
      Arrays.fill(argTypes, String.class);

      try {
          Constructor<?> c = theClass.getConstructor(argTypes);
          Object o = c.newInstance((Object[])args);
          System.out.println("created " + o);
      } catch(ReflectiveOperationException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          System.exit(1);
      }
    }
}
```

The call to `newInstance` doesn't use the varargs feature, as on the source code level, we have an already existing array. In fact, the `(Object[])` cast exists to make it explicit that we don't want to use the varargs feature, i.e. we don't want to call a constructor take a single array argument, but a constructor taking as many string arguments as the array contains.

Note that your example code's `newInstance(new Object[]{"first", "second"," more"})` wasn't using varargs either, as it constructs an array explicitly, calling `newInstance(Object[])` the same way as the solution of this answer. A varargs call would be `newInstance("first", "second"," more")`, which only works if we know at compile-time that the constructor expects three string arguments.